# Very basic question : A sequence $\{a_n\}\in \ell^2$ determines a function $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ with Fourier coefficients $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This seems to be a stupid question, but I just can't figure it out.
I'm giving a proof that given every sequence $\{a_n\}$ of $\ell^2$ there is a function $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ with Fourier coefficients given precisely as the $a_n$.

Of course, the obvious choice is $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{inx}$. I have quickly verified that $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. The only task remaining is to verify by hand that $f$ has Fourier coefficients precisely $a_n.$ I wanted to write:
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(m) &=  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{inx} \right)e^{-imx} dx\\
    &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(n-m)x} dx\\
    &= a_m
\end{align}
but I'm not sure whether I can interchange the summation and the integral; the most likely method is DCT, but I'm not seeing it. Would appreciate all help.

Comment: This is just basic Hilbert space theory. If $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis then $x =\sum a_ne_n$ converges  whenever $a_n \in \ell^{2}$. Also, $\langle x, e_n \rangle=a_n$ for each $n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I've already seen the convergence, but I'm having difficulty on the verification of the Fourier coefficients. Could you check the last part of my question please?

Comment: Use general Hilbert space theory. No need to bring in any measure theory  if you know that $L^{2}$ is Hilbert space and $(e^{inx})$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Interchange of the sum and the integral comes from continuity of the inner product.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, I get it. So i already know from Hilbert space theory that the coefficients are precisely the inner products. Thanks for the help. I'm still curious as to whether I can justify the interchange, though, I'm a newbie to measure theory so I'm trying to use DCT whenever I can.

Comment: @geetha290krm Just checked your additional comment, thanks again :)